# Как получить элемент инфоблока по значению его свойства?

Tags: битрикс

Нужно по значению имейла получить элемент инфоблока, у которого соответствующее свойство имеется.

Через ajax передается e-mail и должно вернуться значение нужного свойства элемента, т.е., e-mail является своего рода идентификатором.

Пока пытаюсь вернуть хотя бы все значения свойств элементов, но дальше запутался (в API Битрикса новичок).

```
if(CModule::IncludeModule("iblock")) {
    $arSelect = Array();
    $arFilter = Array(
        "IBLOCK_ID" => 52,
        "ACTIVE_DATE"=>"Y",
        "ACTIVE"=>"Y"
    );
    $res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), $arFilter, false, Array(), $arSelect);
    while($ob = $res->GetNextElement()){
        $arFields = $ob->GetFields();
        $db_props = CIBlockElement::GetProperty(52, $arFields['ID'], "sort", "asc", array());
        while($ar_props = $db_props->Fetch()){
            $ar_props2[] = $ar_props;
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($ar_props2);
}
```

Массив следующего вида:

```
Array
    (
        [384] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 384
                [TIMESTAMP_X] => 2018-07-16 14:46:25
                [IBLOCK_ID] => 52
                [NAME] => Наименование
                [ACTIVE] => Y
                [SORT] => 500
                [CODE] => 
                [DEFAULT_VALUE] => 
                [PROPERTY_TYPE] => S
                [ROW_COUNT] => 1
                [COL_COUNT] => 30
                [LIST_TYPE] => L
                [MULTIPLE] => N
                [XML_ID] => 
                [FILE_TYPE] => 
                [MULTIPLE_CNT] => 5
                [TMP_ID] => 
                [LINK_IBLOCK_ID] => 0
                [WITH_DESCRIPTION] => N
                [SEARCHABLE] => N
                [FILTRABLE] => N
                [IS_REQUIRED] => Y
                [VERSION] => 1
                [USER_TYPE] => 
                [USER_TYPE_SETTINGS] => 
                [HINT] => 
                [PROPERTY_VALUE_ID] => 9341290
                [VALUE] => Подрядчик 1
                [DESCRIPTION] => 
                [VALUE_ENUM] => 
                [VALUE_XML_ID] => 
                [VALUE_SORT] => 
                [~VALUE] => Подрядчик 1
                [~DESCRIPTION] => 
                [~NAME] => Наименование
                [~DEFAULT_VALUE] => 
            )

        [385] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 385
                [TIMESTAMP_X] => 2018-07-16 14:46:25
                [IBLOCK_ID] => 52
                [NAME] => Что выполняют
                [ACTIVE] => Y
                [SORT] => 600
                [CODE] => 
                [DEFAULT_VALUE] => 
                [PROPERTY_TYPE] => S
                [ROW_COUNT] => 1
                [COL_COUNT] => 30
                [LIST_TYPE] => L
                [MULTIPLE] => N
                [XML_ID] => 
                [FILE_TYPE] => 
                [MULTIPLE_CNT] => 5
                [TMP_ID] => 
                [LINK_IBLOCK_ID] => 0
                [WITH_DESCRIPTION] => N
                [SEARCHABLE] => N
                [FILTRABLE] => N
                [IS_REQUIRED] => Y
                [VERSION] => 1
                [USER_TYPE] => 
                [USER_TYPE_SETTINGS] => 
                [HINT] => 
                [PROPERTY_VALUE_ID] => 9341295
                [VALUE] => Ремонт компьютеров
                [DESCRIPTION] => 
                [VALUE_ENUM] => 
                [VALUE_XML_ID] => 
                [VALUE_SORT] => 
                [~VALUE] => Ремонт компьютеров
                [~DESCRIPTION] => 
                [~NAME] => Что выполняют
                [~DEFAULT_VALUE] => 
            )

        [386] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 386
                [TIMESTAMP_X] => 2018-07-16 14:46:25
                [IBLOCK_ID] => 52
                [NAME] => E-Mail
                [ACTIVE] => Y
                [SORT] => 700
                [CODE] => 
                [DEFAULT_VALUE] => 
                [PROPERTY_TYPE] => S
                [ROW_COUNT] => 1
                [COL_COUNT] => 30
                [LIST_TYPE] => L
                [MULTIPLE] => N
                [XML_ID] => 
                [FILE_TYPE] => 
                [MULTIPLE_CNT] => 5
                [TMP_ID] => 
                [LINK_IBLOCK_ID] => 0
                [WITH_DESCRIPTION] => N
                [SEARCHABLE] => N
                [FILTRABLE] => N
                [IS_REQUIRED] => Y
                [VERSION] => 1
                [USER_TYPE] => 
                [USER_TYPE_SETTINGS] => 
                [HINT] => 
                [PROPERTY_VALUE_ID] => 9341291
                [VALUE] => podryadchik1@mai.com
                [DESCRIPTION] => 
                [VALUE_ENUM] => 
                [VALUE_XML_ID] => 
                [VALUE_SORT] => 
                [~VALUE] => podryadchik1@mai.com
                [~DESCRIPTION] => 
                [~NAME] => E-Mail
                [~DEFAULT_VALUE] => 
            )

        [387] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 387
                [TIMESTAMP_X] => 2018-07-16 14:46:25
                [IBLOCK_ID] => 52
                [NAME] => Подразделение
                [ACTIVE] => Y
                [SORT] => 800
                [CODE] => 
                [DEFAULT_VALUE] => 
                [PROPERTY_TYPE] => G
                [ROW_COUNT] => 1
                [COL_COUNT] => 30
                [LIST_TYPE] => L
                [MULTIPLE] => Y
                [XML_ID] => 
                [FILE_TYPE] => 
                [MULTIPLE_CNT] => 10
                [TMP_ID] => 
                [LINK_IBLOCK_ID] => 5
                [WITH_DESCRIPTION] => N
                [SEARCHABLE] => N
                [FILTRABLE] => N
                [IS_REQUIRED] => Y
                [VERSION] => 1
                [USER_TYPE] => 
                [USER_TYPE_SETTINGS] => 
                [HINT] => Выберите одно или несколько (зажмите Ctrl)
                [PROPERTY_VALUE_ID] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 9341362
                        [1] => 9341363
                    )

                [VALUE] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 1000
                        [1] => 1001
                    )

                [DESCRIPTION] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                        [1] => 
                    )

                [VALUE_ENUM] => 
                [VALUE_XML_ID] => 
                [VALUE_SORT] => 
                [~VALUE] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 1000
                        [1] => 1001
                    )

                [~DESCRIPTION] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                        [1] => 
                    )

                [~NAME] => Подразделение
                [~DEFAULT_VALUE] => 
            )

        [388] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 388
                [TIMESTAMP_X] => 2018-07-16 14:46:25
                [IBLOCK_ID] => 52
                [NAME] => Контакты IT
                [ACTIVE] => Y
                [SORT] => 900
                [CODE] => 
                [DEFAULT_VALUE] => 
                [PROPERTY_TYPE] => S
                [ROW_COUNT] => 1
                [COL_COUNT] => 30
                [LIST_TYPE] => L
                [MULTIPLE] => N
                [XML_ID] => 
                [FILE_TYPE] => 
                [MULTIPLE_CNT] => 5
                [TMP_ID] => 
                [LINK_IBLOCK_ID] => 0
                [WITH_DESCRIPTION] => N
                [SEARCHABLE] => N
                [FILTRABLE] => N
                [IS_REQUIRED] => Y
                [VERSION] => 1
                [USER_TYPE] => HTML
                [USER_TYPE_SETTINGS] => Array
                    (
                        [height] => 200
                    )

                [HINT] => 
                [PROPERTY_VALUE_ID] => 9341365
                [VALUE] => Array
                    (
                        [TEXT] => 12345
                        [TYPE] => html
                    )

                [DESCRIPTION] => 
                [VALUE_ENUM] => 
                [VALUE_XML_ID] => 
                [VALUE_SORT] => 
                [~VALUE] => Array
                    (
                        [TEXT] => 12345
                        [TYPE] => html
                    )

                [~DESCRIPTION] => 
                [~NAME] => Контакты IT
                [~DEFAULT_VALUE] => 
            )

    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Для этого лучше всего использовать `[CIBlockElement::GetList][1]`. Предположим, что свойство инфоблока в котором хранится email имеет код `EMAIL` и с типом строка, множественного значения нет, а значение email в переменной `$email`.

В этом случае код может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
<?php
$arOrder = array();
$arFilter = array("IBLOCK_ID" => 52, "ACTIVE" => "Y", "ACTIVE_DATE"=>"Y", "PROPERTY_EMAIL" => $email);
$arSelectFields = array();
$res = CIBlockElement::GetList($arOrder, $arFilter, false, false, $arSelectFields);
while($ob = $res->GetNextElement())
{
    $arFields = $ob->GetFields();
    print_r($arFields);
}
?>
```

В результате вы получите список элементов инфоблока со всеми их значениями свойств, в свойстве `EMAIL` которых содержится искомый email.

Comment: У меня нет значения "PROPERTY_EMAIL", а результат $arFields = $ob->GetProperties(); выводится в виде Array([384] => Array(...[VALUE]=>email@email.email...)), как в этом случае будет выглядеть $arFilter?

Comment: @Сергей а вот в каком массиве лежит `[VALUE]=>email@email.email`? посмотрите его название и подставьте вместо EMAIL я название кода свойства привел только для примера

Comment: @ Nikolaj Sarry приложил массив. Что в данном случае подставить вместо "PROPERTY_EMAIL"?

Comment: уберите пока GetProperty. вместо EMAIL подставьте то значение, которое отображается в поле символьный код или код в списке свойств инфоблока